# iPhone hm-10 communication. the ble device isn't listed in iPhone

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ios-bluetooth, hm-10

Hello all am trying to pair HM-10 ble Module with an iPhone but the ble device isn't listed in iPhone while searching . but while trying on an android device i can pair and communicate withe module . anyone please help me whether anything i should do before trying to pair with iPhone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't pair BLE devices like a HM-10 with an iOS device in settings.  In your app you can use Core Bluetooth to discover and connect to the device.  If you want a quick test you can use the free [LightBlue Explorer App](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/lightblue-explorer-bluetooth/id557428110?mt=8)